# FormCollection returns a null value in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formcollection

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection fc)
    {
        String sc = fc["SearchString"]; 
        return RedirectToAction("SearchFromObject", new { id = sc });
    }

    public ActionResult SearchFromObject(string searchString)
    {
        var Items = from m in db.Objects
                    select m;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            Items = Items.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString));
        }
        return View(Items);
    }
```

This code returns null value for String sc. why is it?? In my view there is a text box.i want to pass that value to SearchFromObject method as a parameter when click the button and retrieve data related to searched keyword..Here is my view

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}

<h2>Search</h2>
<p>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{<p>
    Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />
    <input type ="submit" value="Search" />
</p>
}
```

Comment: can you show rendered html of your View? Seem ok right now to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method

```
public ActionResult SearchFromObject(string searchString)
```

has a parameter named `searchString`, but in the `Index()` POST method, you try to pass a parameter named `id` using `new { id = sc }`. Its not the value of `sc` which is `null`, its the value of `searchString` in the second GET method that's `null`!

Change the POST method signature to

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult Index(string SearchString)
{
  return RedirectToAction("SearchFromObject", new { searchString = SearchString});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify your post method, controller name and form action like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Default1", FormMethod.Post))
{    
  <p>
  Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />
  <input type ="submit" value="Search" />
</p>
}
```

Comment: `@using (Html.BeginForm())` will add the default values which will be exactly what your have done (assuming the controller name is `Default1Controller`) so this is unnecessary unless your specifying a different controller or action